# bxslider-4 speeds up when adding images

Tags: jquery, performance, reload, bxslider

I have a page which gets all its content via ajax calls.
I also get the images for my slider via an ajax call. I setting the whole content of my slider DIV with getElem...ByID('slider').innerHTML = "DIV ID='bxslider'>...etc.
then:

```
 var bxSlider = $('.bx-pager2').bxSlider({
            mode: 'horizontal',     //'vertical',
            ticker: true,
            tickerHover: true,
            tickerspeed: 50000,
            infiniteLoop: true,
            speed: 20000,
            autoHover: false,
            minSlides: 4,
            maxSlides: 4,
            slideWidth: 150,
            slideMargin: 10,
            responsive: true,
            useCSS: false,
            startSlide: 0

        });
```

The problem is:
after loading new images into the slider DIV , the speed differs, loading e.g. 50 images into the slider makes the speed going up, that you cannot recognize anything on the images.

I tried to implement here a bxslider.reload(), but this makes the slider loader for unknown (long) time.

Any ideas?

Comment: Show us how you're loading the images or a demo. There's not much to go on here.

Comment: the problem might be in the tickerspeed, this github says the maximum value should be 5000 : https://github.com/wandoledzep/bxslider/issues/133

"// float - use value between 1 and 5000 to determine ticker speed - the smaller the value the faster the ticker speed"

Comment: Are **tickerspeed** and **speed** in millisecs? If s actual values make it slow

Comment: You may find the example here: http://boiled-ice.de/!test/test2.html

Comment: Just a guess - maybe the files need different names?

Comment: No, with differnt images, its just the same

Comment: The example i created at boiled-ice.de/!test/test2.html does not add images anymore, the problem just arrives using many images and the following config:
{  
$(document).ready(function(){
    
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    mode: 'horizontal',  
    ticker: true,
    minSlides: 6,
    maxSlides: 6,
    slideWidth: 120,
    slideMargin: 10,
    responsive: true,
    useCSS: false,
    startSlide: 0
});
  });
}

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this problem myself and while this isn't really a solution it is certainly an explanation. If you go to the git and hit up line 907 of the js you'll see that the speed is calculated as a ratio which depends on the total horizontal dimension of the slider.

For me this is hugely problematic because I'm running multiple sliders on one page and each one is dynamically fed a different number of images. I've manipulated the default behavior of the ticker so that it only goes on hover and now they are all going at different speeds, some of them absurdly fast. Anyone have any input given this new information?

Comment: This seems like it could be better as a comment...comments can be pretty long and include links.  Are you sure this is an answer?

Comment: I can't seem to comment without 50 reputation. This seems like valuable enough information to where it deserves to be on the page so I went the whatever it takes route :)

Comment: That's true.  You can't comment on other's answers yet.  If you get deleted, you could also make this as a new question and include  link back.  But I certainly get your point, @b3smith13.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this by calculating how many images there are in the slider. I've chosen the speed 5000 for each image.

I think the confusing bit about the speed is that is calculated per image.

HTML:

```
<ul class="bxslider-ticker">
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt=""></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
  //Count the number of li elements
  var n = $( ".bxslider-ticker li" ).length;

  var ticker = $('.bxslider-ticker').bxSlider({
    minSlides: 1,
    maxSlides: 100,
    slideWidth: 200,
    slideMargin: 10,
    ticker: true,
    mode: 'horizontal',
    tickerHover: true,
    //Multiply the number of li elements with 5000
    speed: 5000*n
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing solution - Saved a good bit of time resolving the issue!